# What value do I pass to `xrandr --output`?

Tags: linux, unix, xorg, bsd

I wish to add a new modeline using `xrandr`, however when I want to switch to the new modeline, I am asked to provide `--output`. The manual page doesn't explain where I can get my options from.

So how do I find out what value to pass to `--output`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xrandr` wants to know which output port you want to apply the new modeline to. Most modern graphics hardware supports more than one output port, for example an HDMI port plus a VGA port on a graphics hard or an internal LCD screen plus an external port on a laptop.

Run `xrandr` without any arguments to see a list of available outputs. The names of the outputs are usually of the form `VGA1` or `LVDS1`. This will also tell you whether or not each output is connected and what its resolution and available modelines currently are.

Comment: It might be helpful to add that this is usually of the form ‘VGA1’ or ‘LVDS1’ etc.

Comment: @Claudius good idea. I've added that. Also, please feel free to edit answers yourself if you have something useful to add!